# MDX Query Problem

Tags: mdx

Im new to MDX . I am trying to perform the following result.

```
Attended Client Count              Client Count

---------------------             -----------------

723                                  1223
```

And I tried to do this :

```
WITH MEMBER [Attended Client] AS
        [Measures].[Client Count]

SET [Attended Client Set] AS
FILTER
(
    [Dim Client Attendance].[Attended].&[Attended],
    [Measures].[Client Count] <>0
)

SELECT {[Measures].[Client Count],[Attended Client] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Client Intervention]
```

And it throws me an error : Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality. I'm able to do [Measures].[Client Count] OR [Attended Client] at a time, but not together. Any solution for this??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) about a gentle introduction to MDX where you can have a look for tuples/sets. The following query should do what you want:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Attended Client Client] AS
  Aggregate( FILTER ( 
               [Dim Client Attendance].[Attended].&[Attended], 
               [Measures].[Client)Count] <>0
             ),
             [Measures].[Client Count]
  )

SELECT {[Measures].[Attended Client Client],[Measures].[Client Count] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Client Intervention]
```